# Deploy a matlab function and use it in c# (.dll-File). ErrorCode -2147467259

Tags: c#, matlab

i deployed my Matlab function to .NET Assembly using Matlab Deploy Tool. This will create a .dll file -> i referenced to this dll file and also to the Matlab Application Type Libary in my c# project.

At my PC i get this message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\z003dukj\Documents\MATLAB\maerz");// Funktion die exekutiert werden soll
            object result = null;
            //string var1 = "Mat.txt"; //CSharp_Schnittstelle\Matlab_Export_dll hier müsste das File sein
            string var1 = @"d C:\Users\z003dukj\Documents\MATLAB\MatlabExport_1";
            // Call the MATLAB function 
            matlab.Feval("maerz27", 1, out result, var1);


        }
    }
}


**$exception    {""}    System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}**
```